# Clang c++11 narrowing

Tags: c++, clang

If I compile my gcc code against clang I got an error:

```
non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int' to 'BYTE' (aka 'unsigned char') in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]
```

this on line:

```
const BYTE pattern[4] = {0x00, 0x00, m_outTrackFormat == BS_RTF_MODE2_FORM1 ? 0x80 : 0x00, 0x00};
```

What has changed here?

Answer (score 1):

The [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) narrowing conversions are defined as follows:

> list-initialization limits the allowed implicit conversions by
> prohibiting the following:
>
> ...
>
> conversion from integer or unscoped
> enumeration type to integer type that cannot represent all values of
> the original, **except where source is a constant expression whose value
> can be stored exactly in the target type**

And there are no 8-bit [integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) in C++. So, unlike the other arguments, as your ternary operator uses non-constant variable you have a non-constant `int` argument, which needs to be converted to `BYTE`, thus the compilation error.

By the way I could reproduce it in both clang and gcc.

Comment: I do not know where in that peace of code is an int. There is only a global define, is this a int for the compile? BTW, the gcc compile the code well, just clang nags.

Comment: 0x80 and 0x00 have the type int, because that is the smallest type for integer literals